# reconnectable websocket which drops message while reconnecting

Tags: go, channel

I'm implementing websocket client with golang.
I have to send several messages in one websocket session.
To deal with network problem, I need to re-connect to websocket server whenever a connection is accidentally closed.
Currently I'm thinking of implementation like this.

```
for {
    select {
        case t := <-message:
            err := connection.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(t.String()))
            if err != nil {
               // If session is disconnected.
               // Try to reconnect session here.
               connection.reconnect()
            }
        case t := <- errSignal:
            panic()
    }
}
```

In an above example, messages stacks while reconnecting.
This is not preferable for my purpose.
How can I drop websocket messages while reconnecting?

Comment: So `message` is a buffered channel, right?  Are you saying you want to delete any messages that get added to the channel during `connection.reconnect()`?

Comment: Yes. I want to delete any messages during reconnect.  
I was thinking `message` is a just a channel.   
But it's ok to change it into bufferd channel.

Comment: If it's an unbuffered channel, then no elements could be sent to the channel during the reconnect anyway, assuming this is your only receive operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> messages stacks while reconnecting.
>   This is not preferable for my purpose.
>   How can I drop websocket messages while reconnecting?

I take it `message` is a buffered channel.  It's not clear to me exactly what behavior you're asking for with regard to dropping websocket messages while reconnecting, or why you want to do that, but you have some options for tracking messages related to the reconnect and handling them however you want.

First off, buffered channels act like queues: first in, first out (FIFO).  You can always pop an element off the channel with a receive operation.  You don't need to pass this to a variable or use it.  So say you just wanted to remove the first two messages from the queue around the reconnect and do nothing with them (not sure why), you can:

```
if err != nil {
     // If session is disconnected.
     // Try to reconnect session here.
     connection.reconnect()
     // drop the next two messages
     <-message
     <-message
}
```

But that's going to remove the messages from the front of the queue.  If the queue wasn't empty when you started the reconnect, it won't specifically remove the messages added during the reconnect.

If you want to relate the number of messages removed to the number of messages added during the reconnect, you can use the channel length:

```
before := len(message)
connection.reconnect()
after := len(message)
for x := 0; x < after - before; x++ {
    <-message
}
```

Again, that will remove from the front of the queue, and I don't know why you would want to do that unless you're just trying to empty the channel.

And if the channel is non-empty at the start of the reconnect and you really want to drop the messages that got added during the reconnect, you can use [the `time` package](https://golang.org/pkg/time/).  Channels can be defined for any Go type.  So create a struct with fields for the message and a timestamp, redefine your buffered `message` channel to the struct type, and set the timestamp before sending the message.  Save a "before" timestamp from before the reconnect and an "after" afterward.  Then before processing a received message you can check whether it's in an after/before window and delete it (not write it) if so.  You could make a new data structure to save several before/after windows, methods on the type to check whether a given time falls within any.  Again, I don't know why you would want to do this.

Perhaps a better solution would be to just limit the buffer size of the channel instead, and then no new messages could be added to the channel when the channel is full.  Would that meet your needs?  If you have a reason to drop messages maybe you can explain more about your goals and design -- especially to explain which messages you want to drop.

It might also clarify your question if you include more of the relevant code, such as the declaration of the message channel.

---

Edit: Asker added info in comment to this answer, and comment to question.

The choice between a buffered channel and an unbuffered channel is, in part, about whether you want senders to block when receivers are not available.  If this is your only receiver, during the reconnect it will be unavailable.  Therefore if it works for your design for senders to block, you can use an unbuffered channel instead of timestamps and no messages will be added to the channel during the reconnect.  However, senders blocked at the channel send will be waiting for the receiver with their old message, and only after that send succeeds will they send a new message with current data.  If that doesn't work for you, a buffered channel is probably the better option.

Comment: HI @jrefior.  
Thaks for your answer.  
I'm making some kind of GPS application.  
A GPS device sends GPS info with websocket(1 GPS/sec).    
I want to show  a current location on a map.   
In my application, it's important to draw locations in an almost real-time way.  
If GPS data stacks on server, my app suddenly receive many GPS data and shows fast-moving point.  
This is not good for my app.  
If I drop GPS data, my app receive GPS data at same interval.   
In this case, My app may show hopping GPS data, but this is tolerablie.

Comment: I think your `time package` solution is good for my purpose. Thank you!